# Create a Log in VB 2008 with MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

im a newbie and I want to create a Log in using Windows Form only, I have 2 textbox, the Username and Password and OK button, I want it to connect to MS Access, there are lot of accounts there, the filename is "Sunergeos Data.accdb" can you please help me with this?

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: @Senthilkumar The codes of a log in, where youll need to input username and password, and compare what you type in the textbox into the MS ACCESS to know if the input is incorrect. The username and passwords are inside the MS ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub btnLogIn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogIn.Click
Conn()
Dim Chklog as Boolean
Cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblLogin where Uname=@Uname and pass =@Pass",con)
Cmd.Parameters .AddWithValue ("@Uname", txtUname.Text)
Cmd.Parameters .AddWithValue ("@Pass", txtPass.Text)
Chklog = Convert.ToBoolean(Cmd.ExcuteScalar())
If Chklog = True Then
 Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx")
Else
'Do something
End If
End Sub
```